# How to install vsdoc js file in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, vsdoc

I know vsdoc.js files are used to provide intellisense in Visual Studio and are added by the Nuget packages automatically. But How can i install a vsdoc.js file manually from scratch let's say i have a vsdoc.js file and i want to add such that visual studio start displaying intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

In my Asp MVC Project I have file called **_references.js** in *Scripts* directory. 
Then in this file I just specify path:

```
/// <reference path="vs-docs-file-name.js" />
```